# How to disable button when input is empty in Vue?

Tags: vuejs2, binding

I'd bind a button to input using v-bind with a function :

The code inside my **template** :

```
<template>
  <input
    type="email"
    v-model="email"
    v-bind:placeholder="$t('fields.email_place_holder')"
  />
  <input
    v-bind:disabled="{ isDisable }"
    type="submit"
    v-bind:value="$t('buttons.notify_me')"
    class="notify-me-button"
  />
</template>
```

The code inside my **script** :

```
  methods: {
    isDisable() {
      return email.lenght > 0;
    }
  }
```

But the `button` does not change its status , I tried to change the **css style** with the same way and the result is the same.The problem is that button responds once time on the first value returned by `isDisable()`.

Comment: Try converting `isDisable` to a computed property instead or replace `isDisable` with the condition you're checking for. i.e.

`<input :disabled="email.length > 0" type="submit" v-bind:value="$t('buttons.notify_me')" class="notify-me-button" />`

Comment: Directives requires only values not statements and conditions.

Comment: Also , when I test with `console.log()` I find that method  executes once time not each time I type in the field.

Comment: If you choose to follow the directives using only values and not statements or expressions, then use a computed property 

`computed: { emailLength: function () { return this.email.lenght > 0;}}`
The reason why the method executes only once is that it's not reactive. This is reactive and would change as the value of `email` changes.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The button isn't disabled because the binding `disabled=isDisable` is not reactive.

It's not reactive because the bound value `isDisable` is not a reactive property (in either `data` or `computed`) and it is not a method that has any reactive parameters i.e. it's called once/evaluated to the constant `false`. Vue won't check if there's reactive properties in the method body, after all methods are supposed to explicitly called in your code.

There's few ways you can fix this:

1. Make `isDisable` a computed property instead:

```
computed: {
  isDisable() {
    return this.email.length > 0;
  }
}
```

2. Pass a reactive property (e.g. `email`) as a parameter to your method so Vue knows to update the binding.

```
<input
  type="submit"
  :disabled="isDisable(email)"
/>
```

```
methods: {
  isDisable(email) {
    return email.length > 0;
  }
}
```

3. Directly bind a statement or condition that includes your reactive property (`email`). This is allowed.

```
<input
  type="submit"
  :disabled="email.length > 0"
/>
```

[Working example on JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9pfrcxkw/)

These would be the obvious (and perhaps idiomatic) approaches to fix this, but there are others e.g. using a watcher.

Note there's also typos in your provided code, e.g.:

- `:disabled="{isDisable}"` is an not a valid binding due to the curly braces
- `isDisable(){ return email.lenght > 0 }` should be `length` not `lenght`

Answer (score 5):

The easy way to do it is to check if the value exists or not.
For example:

```
<input type="text" v-model="user.name" required />
```

For the submit button just use disable

```
<button type="submit" :disabled="!user.name">Submit</button>
```

Only when the field is filled then the submit button is enabled for submit.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm ripple-surface" v- 
  bind:disabled='!isDisabled'>Save</button>
```

```js
   computed: {
        isDisabled() {
        return this.categoryName.length > 0;
    }
},
```